# Normalisation for a two fermion state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, fermions

I'm trying to follow [this paper (Fermion and boson beam-splitter statistics. Rodney Loudon. (1998). Phys. Rev. A 58, 4904)](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.58.4904)
However, I don't quite understand where some of his results come from.

*Question 1*: equation 2.6 is the state for two fermions in arm 1.
$$
\vert 11 \rangle = (1-|I|^2 )^{-1/2}  
\hat\psi^\dagger _{1i} 
\hat\psi^\dagger _{1j}
\vert 0 \rangle
\tag{2.6}
$$
where $\hat\psi^\dagger _{1i,j} = \int dr \psi_{1i,j} (r) \hat a_1 ^\dagger (r)$ are two normalisaerd but not necessarily orthogonal wave functions. And their overlap is defined as $I = \int dr \psi_{i}^\ast (r) \psi_{j}(r)$.

I tried to derive the normalisation factor $(1-|I|^2)$ by computing
$$
\begin{align}
\langle 0 | 
\hat\psi_{1j} 
\hat\psi_{1i}
\hat\psi^\dagger _{1i} 
\hat\psi^\dagger _{1j}
\vert 0 \rangle
&= \int dr' dr ds ds' 
\psi^\ast _{1j}(r')
\psi^\ast _{1i}(r)
\psi_{1i}(ds)
\psi_{1j}(ds')
\langle 0| 
\hat a (r')
\hat a (r)
\hat a (s)
\hat a (s')
|0\rangle.
\end{align}
$$
The last term, due to fermion Pauli's exclusion principles,
$$
\langle 0| 
\hat a (r')
\hat a (r)
\hat a (s)
\hat a (s')
|0\rangle
= \delta (r'-s') \delta (r-s)
\text{ except }
r'=r \text{ or } s=s'.
$$
So the normalisation becomes
$$
\begin{align}
&\int dr'dr \psi_{1j}^\ast(r') \psi_{1i}^\ast(r) \psi_{1i}(r) \psi_{1j}(r') 
- 
\int dr  \psi_{1j}^\ast(r) \psi_{1i}^\ast(r) \psi_{1i}(r) \psi_{1j}(r) 
\\
=&
1- \int dr  \psi_{1j}^\ast(r) \psi_{1i}^\ast(r) \psi_{1i}(r) \psi_{1j}(r) 
\\
\not = &
1- |I|^2.
\end{align}
$$

*Question 2*:
equation 2.7 and 2.9 describes one fermion in each arm 1 and 2,
$$
\begin{align}
|12\rangle_- &= \big(2(1-|I|^2)\big)^{-1/2} 
\big( \hat \psi_{1i}^\dagger \hat \psi_{2j}^\dagger  - \hat \psi_{1j}^\dagger \hat \psi_{2i}^\dagger \big)
\tag{2.7}
\\
|12\rangle_+ &= \big(2(1-|I|^2)\big)^{-1/2} 
\big( \hat \psi_{1i}^\dagger \hat \psi_{2j}^\dagger  + \hat \psi_{1j}^\dagger \hat \psi_{2i}^\dagger \big)
\tag{2.9}
\end{align}
$$
I tried chasing his references, but I still can't figure out why the fermion state is set up like this. In particular, in the lab, I can prepare fermions flying from arm 1 to always in mode $i$, and never $j$, then it seems this formalism would fail.

Another issue is since $\hat a_i \hat a_j = - \hat a_j \hat a_i$, couldn't I rearrange the terms so that $|12\rangle_-$ is just $\propto \hat \psi_{1i}^\dagger \hat \psi_{2j}^\dagger |0\rangle$.

*Question 3*:
This paper defines the beam-splitter as
$$
\begin{align}
\hat a_3 \leftarrow r \hat a_1 + t \hat a_2
\\
\hat a_4 \leftarrow t \hat a_1 + t \hat a_2
\end{align} 
\tag{3.1}
$$
where $r$ and $t$ are the reflection and transmission coefficients. But this does not seem unitary to me unless those coefficients are not real.